# Selenium RC is not filling in password field

Tags: selenium, passwords, field, selenium-rc

I'm running selenium RC with TestNG and filling in a registration page.  This page contains stuff like name, email, password, etc.
All fields are filled in as I expect EXCEPT the password and confirm password fields.  Those two remain blank.  I've searched several forums (including this one) in vain for a solution.

One post on this forum suggested this:
    char[] password = {'p','a','s','s','w','o','r','d'};
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        selenium.keyPress("password", password[i]);
    }

The problem with it was that it failed on keyPress because String is expected, not char.  I wonder how this worked.

Here is the source under test:
    `<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$EmailTextBox" type="text" maxlength="64"     id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_EmailTextBox" class="tahname" />
    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$PasswordTextBox" type="password" maxlength="80" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_PasswordTextBox" class="tahname" />
    <input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ConfirmPasswordTextBox" type="password"   id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ConfirmPasswordTextBox" class="tahname" />`

Here's my selenium code

```
selenium.type(emailLocator, "me@here.com");
selenium.type(passwordLocator, "password");
selenium.type(confirmPasswordLocator, "password");
```

I've double checked the locators for all three text boxes.  No problem there.  The email textbox is filled in fine.  The password and confirmPassword text boxes are blank after execution.
I did note that for the password textboxes type="password".  Do I need to handle these in a different way?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Share the HTML code or Share the URL if it is an open application.

Comment: Manigandan, I forgot to enclose my html in back ticks.  It should be viewable now.

Comment: Isn't your input hidden and when clicked is visible?

Answer (score 0):

Caution: I didn't try this with Selenium, however the method I describe here worked in a different but related scenario.

- change the password field type to text;
- fill it in with the desired value;
- change back to password.

Comment: Alex, I can't change the html (except to test I suppose) so i don't think this solution will work for me.